# How do I make UITextView's tappable links NOT have an underline?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I'm setting up a `UITextView`, and it has links that you can tap that will open in Safari.

```
UITextView *tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 100, 300, 400)];

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[@"<a href='http://google.ca'>test</a>" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:@{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: @(NSUTF8StringEncoding)} documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
tv.attributedText = attributedString;

[self.view addSubview:tv];
```

It basically takes an HTML string in (with an `<a href=...` in it) and then using the HTML parsing methods in iOS 7 gives me my tappable `UITextView` links.

However, if I add the following line before I add the text view to my view:

```
tv.linkTextAttributes = @{
    NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleNone)
};
```

Nothing changes. I can set it to be `NSUnderlineStyleThick` and it gets thicker. I can change the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` to `[UIColor redColor]` to make the text red, but I cannot figure out how to get the text to not have an underline.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Haven't tried this, but... Try adding CSS to your original HTML and see if it translates across to the attributed string in the text view?

Comment: That seems like a little hacky. :/

Comment: Really? I think what _you're_ doing is hacky. If you are going to use an attributed string, you should not be setting the text view's `linkTextAttributes` at all - you should be doing _everything_ with the string attributes.

Comment: Why are those mutually exclusive?

Comment: Hey, I'm just giving you the benefit of my experience. My experience is that attributed string underlining is buggy, and you have to play around with it to get it to obey you...

Comment: Fair enough, I'll play around some. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str` instead of `NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data`. Links will automatic detected and not underline

Try to use code below:

```
NSString *str = @"http://google.ca";
NSAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:str];
tv.attributedText = attributedString;
```